# Jira API not giving expected response

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, burndowncharts

I am working to get Jira burndown chart details using REST API call and using */rest/greenhopper/1.0/rapid/charts/scopechangeburndownchart.json?* API to get chart details.

It worked fine for me in most of the case but for one sprint I am not able to get StatC field in my Json response although that sprint has story points and Jira internal reports are showing correct graph of that sprint.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked API calls of my Jira using inspect element and find out that they were passing customfield with their rapidviewId and sprintID like this */rest/greenhopper/1.0/rapid/charts/scopechangeburndownchart.json?rapidViewId=111&sprintId=111&estimate=field_customfield_111*

I tried it in my code and found actual results for my burndown chart.